# Ionos email account blocks Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer for a website, and everything works fine emails get sent. The website and email is on Ionos.
After a few days though I always get a warning message on the Email account that it has detected strange activity on the account and I have to change the password, if I ignore the message I can't send or receive any further Email.

Is this a common problem with Nodemailer? Is there a way to prevent this or is there a better mail solution I could use where it's less of a chance of this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Nodemailer a lot of the time needs insecure app access, ionos email client doesn't and will not use insecure app access this means,  this is a problem with ionos not being insecure allowing the API to connect to the email client